# \hline with \only (or \onslide) in Beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, rules

In a table in `beamer`, I would like to remove `\hline` after X number of slides using

```
\only<1>{\hline}
```

But this always results in an error message:

> Misplaced `\noalign`

What can I do to overcome this (other than create a new table on the following slide)?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{*5{c}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \only<2>{5}\\
\only<1>{\hline}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Edit:

Marco Daniel's answer does fix what I asked for above. However, it does not work when the second row begins with a `multicolumn`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{*5{c}}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & \only<1>{5}\only<2>{\multirow{2}{*}{5}}
\onslide<1>{\\\hline}\onslide<2>{\\[-\normalbaselineskip]}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & \only<1>{5}\only<2>{}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> Misplaced `\omit`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must put the complete statement in `\onslide`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{*5{c}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \only<2>{5}
\onslide<1>{\\\hline}
\onslide<2->{\\[-\normalbaselineskip]}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That did indeed do what I asked for. But in my real example, it didn't. I've narrowed it down to being caused by ``\multicolumn`` in the next row. I'm adding this to my original question.

Comment: @Sverre: You can put an extra `\\[-\normalbaselineskip]` before `\multicolumn`.