# What's wrong with this table code in beamer?

Tags: tables, beamer

I've been struggling for a long while with this code trying to solve the problem there apparently is. I basically copied the code from this page http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables in the "Spanning in both directions simultaneously" section, and I just modified it a bit:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\onslide<1->\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
\cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Matemáticas} \pause\\
\cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{2} {c}{Cantidad}& \multicolumn{2} {c}{Magnitud} \pause \\ 
\cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c} {Aritmética} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Música} & \multicolumn{1}c}{Geometría}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Astronomía} \pause\\
\cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Quatrivium}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
```

TeXStudio keeps saying:

```
Misplaced \omit \cline{1-4} 
Missing \endgroup inserted \cline{1-4}
Missing } inserted \cline{1-4}
Missing \cr inserted \cline{1-4}
```

I would like that the table ends up looking like this

[image]

Comment: Did you read section 23.5 “Uncovering a Table Rowwise” in the beamer documentation?

Comment: I think this is the same as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108700/hline-with-only-or-onslide-in-beamer

Comment: Hi egreg. You might have noticed that I'm a noob using LaTeX, so... where could I read that documentation??

Comment: Only from the point of view of the table format, a couple of suggestion. First, You can use `\hline` instead of `\cline{1-4}` since your table has 4 columns. Second, you don't need to use `\multicolumn` to span a single column, substitute `\multicolumn{1}{c}{<something>}` by simply `<something>`. Third, for having the format of the image you missed some `|` in your code

Comment: In addtion, replacing \cline{1-4} to \hline gives plenty of other errors (I think I just edited the last post of someone, and it was deleted. SORRY!)

Comment: What is the animation effect you want to achieve?

Comment: Basically, in the first slide there would only be the first row, and in the following slides, the rest of the rows would be appearing one at a time.

Comment: @miguelpiquet: In MikTeX and TeXLive, command `texdoc name-of-package` will open package's documentation. Sometimes, package name and documentation name are different. For `beamer` type `texdoc beameruserguide`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your basic problem is that your table contains for columns, but you have placed `\pause` after `\multicolumn{4}{...}{...}`. At this point, there is no cell. `\pause` can be put at the end of the last argument of `\multicolumn`:

```
\multicolumn{4}{...}{...\pause}
```

But then the bottom line of the row is omitted. The following example smuggles `\pause` after the line:

```
\hline % \cline{1-4}
\noalign{\hbox{\pause}}
```

Remarks:

- `\hline` is better than `\cline{1-<max column>}`, because then the space for the line is taken into account. This is not possible for `\cline`. Otherwise several `\cline` in a row would be vertically shifted.
- `\noalign` allows to put material in vertical mode outside of the alignment.
- I have wrapped `\pause` into `\hbox`, because `\pause` does not seem to like vertical mode here.

There are many ways to get to the wanted table layout, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\tabstack}[4]{%
  \begingroup
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}%
      \textcolor{#1}{#2}\tabularnewline
      \textcolor{#3}{#4}%
    \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\color{blue}
\setlength\extrarowheight{.7ex}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{
  \tabstack {blue}  {\Large Matemáticas}
            {black} {(el estudio de lo inmutable)}
}\\
\hline
\noalign{\hbox{\pause}}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{
  \tabstack {red}   {\Large Cantidad}
            {black} {(lo discreto)}
} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{
  \tabstack {red}   {\Large Magnitud}
            {black} {(lo continuo)}
}\\
\hline
\noalign{\hbox{\pause}}
\tabstack {black} {absoluta}
          {red}   {\Large Aritmética}
&
\tabstack {black} {relativa}
          {green} {\Large Música}
&
\tabstack {black} {en reposo}
          {red}   {\Large Geometría}
&
\tabstack {black} {enmovimiento}
          {red}   {\Large Astronomía}
\\
\hline
\noalign{\hbox{\pause}}
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{
  \Large \textcolor{blue}{Quatrivium}
} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- For the cells with two lines, I have used a nested `tabular`. `@{}` removes the space that separates columns, because this space is already added by the outer tabular.
- The lines of the tabular are colored by setting the default color for the whole table to the color of the lines.
- The textured background is omitted, because this is much more complicate:

  - The table could be put into a box and an image could be scaled to this dimensions and put behind the table box. But this causes trouble with `\pause`.
  - A monochrome background should be easier, package like `colortbl` allows the setting of a background color, e.g. via `\rowcolor`. The package has also commands for colorizing the lines. However there might be problems with partial overwritten lines by the "background" color.

Comment: That was an awesome answer!! Thank you for such a quick and excellent answer. I'll surely study how this code works, for it seems to be much more difficult than the basic things I've studied. I'm very grateful to you, Heiko!